# Programmatically triggering Ctrl+S

Tags: javascript, events, keyboard

I would like to emit a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> keydown event using JavaScript. Ideally the solution works in most modern browsers (up to IE 9).

I am writing tests and need to test my handler for key bindings. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> is just an example, it can be any key binding with a modifier key. I know about the `keyEvent.initKeyboardEvent()` method but I was not able to use it correctly to trigger the same event I got when printing out the full keyboard event after pressing the key from the keyboard.

Comment: Ctrl+S does nothing in Chrome on my Mac

Comment: It's a great thing that modern browsers do not allow such thing. As a user, I would really hate it to visit a web site and have my browser popup a Save As dialog automatically, don't you think?

Answer (score 7):

> I would like to emit a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> keydown event

You mean, in order to trigger the browser's "Save as" dialog or something? That's not possible for security reasons. It would be a huge security problem if it were - imagine: every web site could arbitrarily trigger browser functions.

Comment: Ok I was not very precise. I am writing tests and need to test my handler for key bindings. Ctrl+S was just an example, it can be any key binding with a modifier key. I know about the keyEvent.initKeyboardEvent() method but have not been able to use it correctly to trigger the same event I get when printing out the full keyboard event after pressing the key from the keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot and you must not for security reasons (as Pekka already pointed out). You will always require a user interaction in between. Additionally imagine the chance of the browser vendors getting sued by users, as various programmatic keyboard events will have led to spoofing attacks.

See this [post](http://goo.gl/ghyhA0) for alternatives and more details. There is always the flash based copy-and-paste. Here is an elegant  [example](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/). At the same time it is a testimony why the web is moving away from plugin vendors.

There is a similar security mindset applied in case of the [opt-in CORS policy](http://goo.gl/JiYNEE) to access remote content programmatically.

The answer is:
**There is no way to programmatically trigger input keys in the sandboxed browser environment under normal circumstances**.

**Bottomline:** I am not saying it will not be possible in the future, under special browser-modes and/or privileges towards the end-goal of gaming, or similar user-experiences. However prior to entering such modes, the user will be asked for permissions and risks, similar to the [Fullscreen API model](https://www.google.at/search?client=opera&q=w3c%20fullscreen%20api%20permission). ( I included a google search link, as it neatly includes the relevant text lines in search-result)

[image]