# Execute keyboard shortcut with jquery

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to execute a keyboard shortcut with jquery.
Shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> which opens Google Chrome `Inspect Element`.
Tried: http://jsfiddle.net/r80nLhku/1/

Comment: did you try http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_keypress.asp ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[You can't send arbitrary key presses to the window from JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19883789/5195629)... It's a security issue. This would mean you could force any user to literally go to any site (and worse, ie. control their computer).

Comment: thanks for the info. But what about with an extension? Can you help?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8668192/programmatically-triggering-ctrls for a very similar question. What do you mean by extension? A Chrome extension?

Comment: Yes with chrome extension.

Comment: Why would you ever want to do that instead of just hitting the hotkey yourself?