# How to automatically pressed key (ctrl+shift+i) through javascript in documents.ready function?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, dom, keyboard

I want to open automatically inspect element through javascript in documnets.ready function without pressing key on keyboard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar in essence to:
[Programmatically triggering Ctrl+S](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8668192/programmatically-triggering-ctrls/19882728#19882728)

And I believe the given [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19882728/1286358) would apply here too,

> There is no way to programmatically trigger input keys in the
>   sandboxed browser environment under normal circumstances.

but I stand to be corrected.

Comment: But i need specific - want to open inspect elements through javascript,
can you please write code for me ?

Comment: Sorry if there was any confusion. What I was trying to say is. "I don't believe what you are asking to do is possible". Why do you need to do this? There may be other solutions.